# How can we test android app in all devices suggest me

Tags: android, unit-testing

We have this application which was built in flutter, we have tested it on android version 13 (SDK 33) and it seems to work fine, however some android devices happen to face issue
with the application with the same android version, we want suggestions how we can test our application across all devices if not most devices, any application or tool or anything from which we can do it.
We are already using android emulator, other than that to achieve the same.